# Are pro versions of the contracts considered separate for all achievements?

Tags: steam, achievements, payday-2

There are many achievements for completing all contracts on a certain difficulty or from a certain contractor and some of them mention pro jobs, such as:

> **OVERKILL Salutes You!**
>   Complete all contracts *including pro jobs* on the Death Wish difficulty.

But there are also achievements that don't mention pro jobs at all, such as:

> **... For Better or Worse**
>   Complete all of the Elephants contracts on the Death Wish difficulty.

Are the pro jobs considered separate contracts for these achievements as well?

Answer (score 1):

No, for achievements like `...For Better or Worse`, it doesn't matter if the completed job was pro or not.

That is...completing a pro or a non-pro Death Wish job will count towards the achievement.